# Ubuntu Fresh install keeps booting into grub console

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I tried to install 22.04.2 LTS. It was going well and the installer told me the installation was successful. I have the iso flashed onto a usb stick and I am installing Ubuntu onto a 1tb Toshiba External Hard Drive. When I restart my computer after the install, it says to remove the installation medium and press enter; I unplug my usb and press enter. Then it just boots in a Grub console. What is happening?

I am on a Surface Laptop 2 with an Intel i5-8250U and 8gb of ram.

Comment: If you installed to external drive, do you plan to use it on any other system? Did you get an ESP & boot files on external or only on internal drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub bootloader to internal drive. If using drive anywhere else you need boot files on external. Supposed new Subiquity installer has fixed very old issue. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to 'fix' it. I unplugged my mouse when I booted in again and it worked. Maybe my computer was trying to boot the memory on my mouse?